# Changing Domain Name Broke Database

Tags: multisite

I'm running a WordPress Multi Site installation, which I seem to have destroyed.

I created the installation with Plesk.

Using this page: [image]I attempted to change the domain name from www.old.com to www.new.com . I thought I could do this without issue for a multi site.

On the Plesk page for "Websites & Domains", I now see this. It scrolls forever: [image]

I cannot export dump the database, and checking it for errors says that it has none.

Now I get the message "Error establishing a database connection" on every page of my wordpress site. I cannot access wp-login.php either

I did back up the site a week ago (just by FTP downloading all files in the httpdocs folder).

I'm not a web expert; I have no idea what to do and this site is very important for our business.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to your database which is storing the WordPress website and look under the `wp_options` table. You should find under the option name `siteurl` and `home`. Change these to the new updated url for your website.

See this for more information https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Note that Multisite will require some additional work: [Moving WordPress » Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Multisite)

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply. I tried to search for `wp_options` in the PHPMyAdmin page for the database, but it gave 0 results. All string searches for www.new.com also had 0 results; if the URL is still www.old.com, why wouldn't it simply work as it did before? Have I somehow deleted the `wp_options` table required? Can I just delete a database and start again? Thank you..